# Discord REST API: get multiple users

Tags: discord, unirest

I'm trying to query multiple users with a single request by using the Discord REST API with Node.js and the Unirest Module.

```
unirest.get(`https://discord.com/api/v8/users/{user.id}`).headers({ Authorization: `Bot${botSecret}`})
.then(response =>{
   console.log(response);
})
.catch(error =>{
   console.error(error);
})
```

In order to get multiple users, I'm passing in the `user.id` field a list of ids in the following way:
`"id1,id2,id3"`

`https://discord.com/api/v8/users/id1,id2,id3`

However I get a 'Bad Request' response.

Which is the correct way to query multiple users with a single request??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look around the Discord API & discord.js code it seems like they are done individually.

Discord's API doesn't seem to support getting multiple users at once & discord.js gets an array of users, and iterates through them whilst also checking cache, making sure they dont violate ratelimit, etc.